# Get count of unique hosts in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

What query will return the number of distinct hosts in InfluxDB? I have a small army of computers all (hopefully) writing stats to InfluxDB via collectd, but I can't figure out how to count how of the computers are successfully writing.

Edit: Using InfluxDB 0.9.4

Comment: Please mention which version you are using.

Answer (score -1):

If all the hosts are sending a common metric (e.g. "jvm.memory.total.used") and that you are tagging the metrics with the hostname, you can run the following query to get all the unique hostnames:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "jvm.memory.total.used" WITH KEY = "host"
```